# can I migrate/move a openzfs rpool from one computer/disk to another?

Tags: system-installation, zfs, migration, grub-legacy

Can I zfs send/recv the rpool of this system from one disk to another disk on this computer and have *everything* be identical in the environment except for bpool and whatever boot setup? In other words, move it to (for example) a GPT disk with bios_boot partition etc. without losing ANY of the configurations in window manager and so on?

If yes, what are the steps to follow? I don't think I can easily recreate the exact original install on the destination disk because it was a focal install upgraded to jammy.

I assume "cloning" it into a completely different distro (debian/arch) is not possible..?

This is currently a non-bootable openzfs on root ubuntu jammy 22.04 install. This is on a legacy BIOS computer with MBR and an EFI boot partition (ESP) and 2 zpools (bpool&rpool) inside an extended partition.